# What's the purpose of a dynamic database module and the CONNECTION injection token?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

I struggle with understanding what is the purpose of the dynamic database module providing a `'CONNECTION'` dependency injection token to the `TypeOrmModule` in `AppModule`.

Is it so that we can reuse the `TypeOrmModule` from `AppModule` but with a different config? Why can't we simply import the `TypeOrmModule` directly wherever we need it with a different config?

This is from the nestjs fundamentals course.

`TypeOrmModule` configuration in `AppModule` (
https://github.com/jstrother/iluvcoffee/blob/5a34b0d98841f9d33d2490e7186648928303eedb/src/app.module.ts#L21-L34):

```
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CoffeesModule } from './coffees/coffees.module';
import { CoffeeRatingModule } from './coffee-rating/coffee-rating.module';
import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';
import { CommonModule } from './common/common.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CoffeesModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        DATABASE_HOST: Joi.required(),
        DATABASE_PORT: Joi.number().default(5432),
      }),
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: +configService.get<number>('DATABASE_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DATABASE_USER'),
        password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    CoffeeRatingModule,
    DatabaseModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`DatabaseModule` (https://github.com/jstrother/iluvcoffee/blob/5a34b0d98841f9d33d2490e7186648928303eedb/src/database/database.module.ts):

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createConnection, ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

@Module({})
export class DatabaseModule {
  static register(options: ConnectionOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: DatabaseModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'CONNECTION',
          useValue: createConnection(options),
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Using the `DatabaseModule` in another module (https://github.com/jstrother/iluvcoffee/blob/5a34b0d98841f9d33d2490e7186648928303eedb/src/coffee-rating/coffee-rating.module.ts):

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CoffeesModule } from '../coffees/coffees.module';
import { DatabaseModule } from '../database/database.module';
import { CoffeeRatingService } from './coffee-rating.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule.register(
      {
        type: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
      }
    ),
    CoffeesModule
  ],
  providers: [CoffeeRatingService]
})
export class CoffeeRatingModule {}
```

It just seems that using the `DatabaseModule` in that `CoffeeRatingModule` is kinda moot because we already have a database connection with the same config from the `AppModule`... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the core course shows you two different ways to do it (just like the docs do). One already built by NestJS (the `@nestjs/typeorm` package), and one built by you (using the `DatabaseModule`). The `DatabaseModule` approach gives you more freedom because it's made by you, but it also means you'd be responsible for managing the connection yourself, all the dependency tokens, everything, whereas the `@nestjs/typeorm` package does most of that for you, but extending it can be a bit difficult at times.